# Why am I getting this error IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, database, sqlite, kml

I'm trying to pull rows from a database. It pulls the first two rows however will not pull out rows 6 and 7, and it's saying this error: `tuple index out of range`.

```
db = sqlite3.connect('da_destination_history')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''SELECT time, dest_lat, dest_lng, source_lat, source_lng FROM destination_history''')
rows = cursor.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print('{0} : {1}, {2}'.format(row[0], float(row[1])/1000000, float(row[2])/1000000))
    print('{0} : {6}, {7}'.format(row[0], float(row[6])/1000000, float(row[7])/1000000))
    ttime = row[0]
    dlong = float(row[1])/1000000
    dlat = float(row[2])/1000000

kml = simplekml.Kml()
kml.newpoint(name="andriod2", coords=[((float(row[2])/1000000),(float(row[1])/1000000))])
kml.newpoint(name="andriod", coords=[((float(row[7])/1000000),(float(row[6])/1000000))])
kml.save("andriod.kml")
```

Comment: You are selecting only *5 columns*, why do you expect there to be 8 instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martijn indicated the indexing of `row[6]` looks suspicious as you only select 5 columns.

There is also a problem with this `format` function on the string:

```
'{0} : {6}, {7}'.format(row[0], float(row[6])/1000000, float(row[7])/1000000)
```

as `6` and `7` between `{}` indicate the argument to `format()` and you provide only 3 arguments (indexed with `{0}`, `{1}` resp. `{2}`

If you copied this code from some example with more columns selected, you should make sure you update all indices, both in row, as well as in the format instructions.